# Figure one next to the other and hook to equation's points

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, hooks

I would like to connect two figures like the following[image].

The code that I've already have is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pst-tree,array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,>=latex,font=\footnotesize,domain=0:7]
\draw[thick, -] (4.5,3.5)--(7,8) node[above right]{$S$}; 
\draw[dashed] (4.5,3.5)--(0,3.5) node[left]{$P_{\min}$};
  \draw[very thick, <->](0,8)node[left]{$P$}--(0,0)--(8,0)node[below]{$Q$};

\begin{scope}[yshift=10cm,domain=1:7]

  %AVC
  \draw[thick,yscale=.6,name path global=avc] plot (\x,{.2*\x^2-1.8*\x+6})
    node[right]{$AVC$};

  %MC
  \draw[red,thick,yscale=.6,name path global=mc] plot (\x,{.6*\x^2-3.6*\x+6})
    node[right]{$MC$};
  \draw[very thick, <->](0,8)node[left]{$C$}--(0,0)--(8,0)node[below]{$Q$};
\end{scope}

  \draw[name intersections={of=mc and avc, by=mypoint},dashed](mypoint)--(mypoint|-0,0) node[below]{$Q_{\min}$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I would like is to place one figure next to the other.
How could I add the hook so as to show where the supply curve comes from and how the arrow at the point where AVC=MC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the decorations.pathreplacing libary for the brace:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows,
  intersections,
  decorations.pathreplacing
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=.6,
  >=latex,
  font=\footnotesize,
  domain=1:7,
  decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}
  ]
\def\myshift{10}% shift of the right diagram

\foreach \x/\ylabel in {0/C,\myshift/P}
  \draw[very thick, <->](\x,8)node[left]{$\ylabel$}--(\x,0)--(\x+8,0)node[below]{$Q$};
  %AVC
  \draw[thick,yscale=.6,name path global=avc,green!50!black] plot (\x,{.2*\x^2-1.8*\x+6})
    node[right]{$AVC$};
  %MC
  \draw[blue,thick,yscale=.6,name path global=mc] plot (\x,{.6*\x^2-3.6*\x+6})
    node[above right]{$MC$}coordinate(mc1);
  %intersection AVC and MC
  \path[name intersections={of=mc and avc, by=mp1},dashed,thick];
  %shutdown point
  \draw[<-](mp1)--+(-45:1)node[right,align=left,font=\tiny]{SHUTDOWN\\POINT};
  %dashed lines
  \foreach \p in {mc,mp}
    \draw[dashed](\p1)--+(\myshift,0)coordinate(\p2);
  \foreach \i in {1,2}
    \draw[dashed,thick](mp\i)--(mp\i|-0,0) node[below]{$Q_{\min}$};
  %brace
  \draw[decorate](mp1)--node[above left,align=left,font=\tiny,outer xsep=3mm]{SUPPLY\\CURVE}(mc1);
  %lila arrow
  \draw[blue!50!red,->,thick,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm]([xshift=5mm]mp1)--([xshift=5mm]mc1);
  %red line
  \draw[red,thick](mp2)--(mc2)node[below right]{$S$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]